# Make range change value based on checkbox - Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I'm looking to have a checkbox on A3, that when checked makes types "0" on every cell of the range A6:A350. If possible, that unticks itself at the end ubt leaving the values on the range. Now it would be easy using a if condition on that range, the problem is that I want to be able to manually change values if needed.
Can a script do this?

I've looked for this, but can only seem to find the opposite, and without coding background it isnt easy to reverse it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

That can only be done with a script. You can fill a range with zeros like this:

```js
function fillWithZeros() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A6:A350').setValue(0);
}
```

To run that easily, assign `fillWithZeros` to a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets).

If you really need to run it when a checkbox is ticked, use the [checkboxButtons_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/119054769?msgid=120084104) script.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var row;
 var col;
 var sheetName;
 var sheet;

 if(e.value == "TRUE"){
  if((row = e.range.getRow()) == 3 && (col = e.range.getColumn()) == 1){
   if((sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getSheetName()) == "TargetSheet"){
     sheet = e.range.getSheet();
     sheet.getRange(6,col,345,1).setValue(0);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

TargetSheet should be replaced by the name of the sheet that you will be using, this is done so that this function does not change the values of other sheets.

**Edit:** here is the same code rewritten to use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) instead of API calls.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet;
  if (e.value !== 'TRUE'
    || e.range.rowStart !== 3
    || e.range.columnStart !== 1
    || (sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName() !== 'TargetSheet') {
    return;
  }
  sheet.getRange(6, e.range.columnStart, 345, 1).setValue(0);
  e.range.setValue(false);
}
```

Comment: That code will make a minimum of four API calls every time any cell is edited: `Range.getSheet()`, `Sheet.getName()`, `Range.getRow()` and `Range.getColumn()`. When the `if()` test is successful, it will use an additional two API calls. That is wasteful. Use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) instead of API calls to make it run more swiftly. See these [onEdit(e) optimization tips](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).

Comment: Hi doubleunary, thanks for the insight. I have updated the code in order to avoid unnecessary API calls.

Comment: Yes, that's better... but it can still be improved. Edited your answer to show how to do the same with less API calls. Note that the JavaScript `||` [logical "or" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) is short-circuit evaluated.

Comment: Thank your for editing my answer. Your code is perfect. Thanks!